# How to get python recognize row while read csv and put into hbase?

Tags: python

I am trying to read every single row of csv and send them in to message where it will be like:

```
...
    { 'email':'flo.bookamer@cox.net' }
    { 'web':'http://www.simontonhoweschneiderpc.com' }
    { 'ID':'499' }
    { 'first_name':'Jani' }
    { 'last_name':'Biddy' }
    { 'company_name':'Warehouse Office & Paper Prod' }
    { 'address':'61556 W 20th Ave' }
    { 'city':'Seattle' }
    { 'county':'King' }
    { 'state':'WA' }
    { 'zip':'98104' }
    { 'email':'jbiddy@yahoo.com' }
    { 'web':'http://www.warehouseofficepaperprod.com' }
    { 'ID':'500' }
    { 'first_name':'Chauncey' }
    { 'last_name':'Motley' }
   ...
```

The consumer of message suppose to be transform these lines into hbase put lines( for every ID it encounter the key value will be stored in a list and put into database before it find another new ID). My plan is to make python recognize ID header and put them into hbase put command i.e 'ID':'Chauncey' But things got weird I print them out.

Here is my code:

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
import collections
import io
import happybase
import json, ast,string
import struct
# To consume messages
consumer = KafkaConsumer('test', bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092','localhost:9093'])


#hbase connection
connection = happybase.Connection('localhost')
table = connection.table('test6')


d = []
seen = set()
for msg in consumer:
    a = list(msg)
    b = a[-1]
    c = b.split("'") #split message { 'last_name':'Motley' }
    d.append(c[1])
    #c[1] and c[3] are the key value pair  in each message split
    for x in d:
        if x not in seen:
            print c[1], c[3]
            seen.add(c[3])

        elif x in seen:

            d= []
```

> this the result of print on console

```
....
    state FL
    state FL
    state FL
    state FL
    state FL
    state FL
    state FL
    zip 32804
    zip 32804
    zip 32804
    zip 32804
    zip 32804
    zip 32804
    zip 32804
    zip 32804
    phone1 407-413-4842
    phone1 407-413-4842
    phone1 407-413-4842
    phone1 407-413-4842
    phone1 407-413-4842
    phone1 407-413-4842
    phone1 407-413-4842
    phone1 407-413-4842
    phone1 407-413-4842
    phone2 407-557-8857
    phone2 407-557-8857
    phone2 407-557-8857
    phone2 407-557-8857
    phone2 407-557-8857
    phone2 407-557-8857
    phone2 407-557-8857
    phone2 407-557-8857
    phone2 407-557-8857
    phone2 407-557-8857
    email chauncey_motley@aol.com
    email chauncey_motley@aol.com
    email chauncey_motley@aol.com
    email chauncey_motley@aol.com
    email chauncey_motley@aol.com
    email chauncey_motley@aol.com
    email chauncey_motley@aol.com
    email chauncey_motley@aol.com
    email chauncey_motley@aol.com
    email chauncey_motley@aol.com
    email chauncey_motley@aol.com
    web http://www.affiliatedwithtravelodge.com
    web http://www.affiliatedwithtravelodge.com
    web http://www.affiliatedwithtravelodge.com
...
```

Comment: why don't you use the csv module ? https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Comment: Yea, I should be using the module to it up  but I was brute force splitting the lines on a producer. Now I am stuck on consuming it back as I want it to insert  every row per id encountered.